# ES6 instanceof when assigning a type to a variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const Namespace = {
  "FooFunction": () => {
    class MyError extends Error {
      constructor(message) {
        super(message);
      }
    }
    return {"MyError": MyError};
  }
}

console.log((new (Namespace.FooFunction()).MyError("foo")) instanceof Namespace.FooFunction().MyError);
```

This prints false. I am looking for a way to use instanceof against a "type stored in a variable" like this. How can I do this - is it possible?

Comment: your problem is that every time you call `FooFunction` you create a new class. The problem is not that you can not store a type in a variable, but `Namespace.FooFunction().MyError != Namespace.FooFunction().MyError`, they are two classes.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing all this instead of just using an object or class?

Comment: @Lux makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @evolutionbox the purpose is to namespace exceptions so that I can have two different "MyError" classes prefixed by a different namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `Namespace.FooFunction`, it creates a new `MyError` class, so `Namespace.FooFunction().MyError == Namespace.FooFunction().MyError` will never be true.

If you need to keep the `MyError` class declaration within the function as you have it, changing as little as possible, we can convert `FooFunction` to an IIFE, which allows it to return the same `MyError` class on each call:

```js
const Namespace = {
  "FooFunction": (() => {
    class MyError extends Error {
      constructor(message) {
        super(message);
      }
    }
    return (...arguments) => ({"MyError": MyError});
  })()
}

console.log((new (Namespace.FooFunction()).MyError("foo")) instanceof Namespace.FooFunction().MyError);
```

---

Of course a better option would be to add the class to the `Namespace` object itself:

```js
const Namespace = {
  "MyError": class MyError extends Error {
    constructor(message) {
      super(message);
    }
  },
  "FooFunction": function() {
    return {"MyError": this.MyError};
  }
}

console.log((new (Namespace.FooFunction()).MyError("foo")) instanceof Namespace.FooFunction().MyError);
```